# Can't load Slb.Ocean.Petrel.dll into visual studio 2010 toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ocean, petrel

I'm trying to browse to my Slb.Ocean.Petrel.dll in my install path so that I can get the controls in it, mainly DropTarget, but I just get an error...

Could not load file or assembly 'InventorNet, Version=8.1.2.2, Culture=neutral, ....' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's some collision between VS2010 (32bit) and Inventor's dlls (64bit). So, to be able to use functionality in VS2010, try to copy 4 (32bit) dll's to 'Public' folder:

1. InventorBase.dll
2. InventorNet.dll
3. SbLinear.dll
4. SbLinear.netmodule

If you use 64-bit Petrel, you will need to copy those dll's from any 32-bit location.

Hope this helps.